# wxMenuItem in C++: Characters like "äöü" not displayed properly in the item text

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am starting to use wxWidgets (Version 3.1.4) for a Windows GUI application. Compiling and linking is done with gcc coming with MINGW64 (gcc (x86_64-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0).

In the source, the characters are entered correctly:

```
m_menuItem31 = new wxMenuItem(m_name6, wxID_ANY, _("Stückliste drucken"), _("Stückliste drucken"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
m_name6->Append(m_menuItem31);
```

In the application it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot menu texts]

After some research I tried using the linker option -municode ending up in an error "no reference to wWinMain". #define wxUNICODE has no effect.

Edit:
After preprocessing, the characters are still as desired. In the .o file, they are already spoiled, so the solution should be a compiler switch I am not yet aware of...

Any good ideas are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is interpreting your source file as UTF-8?

Comment: to be honest: no. I have built the libraries with unicode, and the compiler has a unicode flag set: g++  -c  "Q:/src/wxcrafter.cpp" -g -Os -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -mthreads -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -D__WXDEBUG__ -D_UNICODE -ID:/Programmierung/wxWidgets-3.1.4/lib/gcc_l. So far I did not find another flag to make sure the interpretation is correct.

Comment: @UltraJunkie, what is the command line you used to build the library? And what command you used to build the application? Are you using any IDE?

Answer (score 1):

This might be up to the encoding of your source file (as VZ hinted) - I am developing wxWidgets C++ app with some non-english (e.g. - ć) characters similar to German umlauts in terms of occasional display problems.
I opened my source file in Notepad++ to see my source file's encoding and it showed encoding was ANSI:

[image]

and when this file was compiled (in MSVC) it produced correct display in application:

[image]

But when in Notepad++ I converted encoding to UTF-8, in source file it still appeared correct:

[image]

I saved file with encoding converted from ANSI to UTF-8 and compiled but after that application showed wrong character:

[image]

I advise you to **take Notepad++ and do similar experiment** and try to find out what encoding you are using and what encoding you should be using in your source files (possibly it should be encoding that the compiler is expecting, as VZ hinted).

In my case it didn't really seem to matter that much if string was bounded in `_()` or `wxT()` - I was able to get correct display when compiled as long as encoding of the source file was correct.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [wx docs](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_unicode.html#overview_unicode_support_default), you can't simply expect `wxMenuItem(...,..., _("Stückliste drucken"),...)` to work, due to that `ü` is not a 7-bit valid character.

You may use

```
_(wxString::FromUTF8("St \xC3\xBC ckliste drucken"))
```

or

```
_(L"St \u00FC ckliste drucken")
```

because `ü` has 00FC Unicode point or C3BC in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Note that you can also use just `L"Stückliste drucken"` too as long as your editor and your compiler use the same character encoding (typically UTF-8).

Comment: `_()` both obtains a translation and marks the string as translatable. Because of the latter, the argument to `_()` should only be a string literal, not a function call; otherwise `xgettext` will fail to extract a translatable string. And if there is no intention of translating anything, `_()` can simply be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it sorted out...

I use Codelite, and after the answer from Ivan (thanks a lot for the hints!) I made some more tests. After adding some of the special characters to the minimal sample of wxWidgets and compiling it from commandline, the characters were displayed wrong in the first place. In Notepad++ I found coding to be UTF-8. After changing it to ANSI, characters were displayed correctly (consistent with Ivan's answer).

I tried the same with Codelite, and it failed. The reason was that the coding of the source file was always reset to UTF-8. It took 2 iterations to get the settings in the Codelite preferences correct (ISO-8859-1 with localization enabled) after which it worked.

The only strange effect I observed was that linking now took about 14 min... need to dig into that further.